# Scope of view.setId

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am populating a viewgroup using a for loop and assigning IDs based on the iteration of the for loop. Something like :

```
For(int i = 0; i<=listLength; i++){
  ImageView iv = new Imageview(this);
  RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
  iv.setId(i);
  iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageResource);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(10, 10);
  if(i==0){
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
  }
  else{
  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, i-1);
  }
  iv.setLayoutParams(params);
  r.addView(iv);
}
```

However, when I try to place the next view relative to that ID, the view always appears in the top left corner of the parent view. The first view is in the right place but the others don't seem to know where the previous view is.

I think that it is because the scope of iv.setId(); is limited to that iteration of the for loop. Is that the reason?

Comment: On the second iteration, you're adding an `ABOVE` rule relative to a `View` with ID 0 - `i-1`. In `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, 0 generally means `false`, and so makes no sense with an `ABOVE` rule, and it is therefore basically ignored. That's why your second `View` ends up in the top-left corner, and then the rest of them are supposed to be `ABOVE` each previous one, but with nowhere to go, they just stack up there. Start your IDs at something greater than 0.

Comment: Aha! Thanks very much Mike!

Comment: Annoyingly, the editor now complains about iv.setId(i); but compiles fine. I found the other issue, which was that I need to specify a horizontal position too.